# ¿Cómo subir una imagen en el Firebase IONIC?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic, app

¡Hola! Os adjunto mi codigo. Estoy haciendo una app ionic que se trata de subir una imagen desde la galería y subirla al firebase.  Ahora mismo solo tengo la opción de escoger la imagen, me queda subirla al Firebase con una función.  Mi app se basa en un mapa de leaflet con unos puntos localizados. El usuario puede añadir un punto/marker con la localización. Puede subir una foto y un comentario del sitio. La cuestión es que no sé cómo subir la imagen en el store firebase ni poner la opción de añadir un comentario.

```
     fileLoader.click();
     var that = this;
     fileLoader.onchange = function () {
       var file = fileLoader.files[0];
       var reader = new FileReader();

       reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
         that.processing = true;
         that.getOrientation(fileLoader.files[0], function (orientation) {
           if (orientation > 1) {
             that.resetOrientation(reader.result, orientation, function (resetBase64Image) {
               that.uploadImage = resetBase64Image;
             });
           } else {
             that.uploadImage = reader.result as string;
           }
         });
       }, false);

       if (file) {
         reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       }
     }
   //this.uploadImageToFirebase(that.uploadImage);
   }

 imageLoaded(){
   this.processing = false;
 }
 getOrientation(file, callback) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function (e:any) {

     var view = new DataView(e.target.result);
     if (view.getUint16(0, false) != 0xFFD8) return callback(-2);
     var length = view.byteLength, offset = 2;
     while (offset < length) {
       var marker = view.getUint16(offset, false);
       offset += 2;
       if (marker == 0xFFE1) {
         if (view.getUint32(offset += 2, false) != 0x45786966) return callback(-1);
         var little = view.getUint16(offset += 6, false) == 0x4949;
         offset += view.getUint32(offset + 4, little);
         var tags = view.getUint16(offset, little);
         offset += 2;
         for (var i = 0; i < tags; i++)
           if (view.getUint16(offset + (i * 12), little) == 0x0112)
             return callback(view.getUint16(offset + (i * 12) + 8, little));
       }
       else if ((marker & 0xFF00) != 0xFF00) break;
       else offset += view.getUint16(offset, false);
     }
     return callback(-1);
   };
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
 }
 resetOrientation(srcBase64, srcOrientation, callback) {
   var img = new Image();

   img.onload = function () {
     var width = img.width,
       height = img.height,
       canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
       ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

     // set proper canvas dimensions before transform & export
     if (4 < srcOrientation && srcOrientation < 9) {
       canvas.width = height;
       canvas.height = width;
     } else {
       canvas.width = width;
       canvas.height = height;
     }

     // transform context before drawing image
     switch (srcOrientation) {
       case 2: ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1, width, 0); break;
       case 3: ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, -1, width, height); break;
       case 4: ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, height); break;
       case 5: ctx.transform(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0); break;
       case 6: ctx.transform(0, 1, -1, 0, height, 0); break;
       case 7: ctx.transform(0, -1, -1, 0, height, width); break;
       case 8: ctx.transform(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, width); break;
       default: break;
     }

     // draw image
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

     // export base64
     callback(canvas.toDataURL());
   };

   img.src = srcBase64;
 }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te diria el proceso pero es que es un poco extenso, asi que te lo resumire por aqui porque tampoco recuerdo bien como se hace, lo que si recuerdo es lo siguiente: debes instalar el plugin de FirebaseStorage o algo asi para poder usarlo en la app, tambien necesitas definir un objeto de configuracion de Firebase que almacenara la informacion para que la aplicacion tenga acceso a tu servidor en Firebase, luego enlazas ambas y por ultimo puedes usar funciones predeterminadas de firebase que te permiten diferentes operaciones (subida, eliminacion) de archivos.

Comment: Ahi ya solo necesitarias un input file o usar algun plugin que te devuelva ya sea un tipo File o un tipo Blob, ya que estos son tipos admitidos para subida directa por firebase.

Comment: ¡¡Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Hola Riven, ¿me sabrias decir el código? ando un poco perdida...

Comment: No te puedo dar el codigo, ya que es una cosa demasiado larga y extensa, aparte las respuestas de ese estilo se considerarian de baja calidad, pero lo que si puedo hacer por ti es proporcionarte el video del que extraje todo aquello que te dije en un inicio, es este, miralo porfavor a ver si te ayuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VoZ7sqyd30